# Looping files in bash

Tags: bash, shell, parallel-processing

I want to loop over these kind of files, where the the files with same Sample_ID have to be used together

```
Sample_51770BL1_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_51770BL1_R2.fastq.gz

Sample_52412_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_52412_R2.fastq.gz
```

e.g. Sample_51770BL1_R1.fastq.gz and Sample_51770BL1_R2.fastq.gz are used together in one command to create an output.

Similarly, Sample_52412_R1.fastq.gz and Sample_52412_R2.fastq.gz are used together to create output.

I want to write a for loop in bash to iterate over and create output.

```
sourcedir=/sourcepath/
destdir=/destinationpath/


bwa-0.7.5a/bwa mem -t 4 human_g1k_v37.fasta Sample_52412_R1.fastq.gz  Sample_52412_R2.fastq.gz>$destdir/Sample_52412_R1_R2.sam
```

How should I pattern match the file names Sample_ID_R1 and Sample_ID_R2 to be used in one command?

Thanks,

Comment: Is the number of files (R1, R2 — hence 2) per sample fixed or can you have more than 2 (or less than 2)?  If you can have varying numbers, how is the output name created with 1, 3, 4 ... suffixes? If the number of files is fixed, what should happen if there's an R2 file without a corresponding R1 file, or vice versa? Is the suffix always `.fastq.gz`? The sample number appears to be the string between the two underscores; could there ever be a file with more than two underscores, or less than two underscores? Could any of the file names ever contain spaces? Could the first word not be 'Sample'?

Comment: The files are two  R1 and R2 only,the output name was created dynamically from a bunch of R1 files and a bunch of R2 files,by extracting the prefix and assigning the final R1 and R2 for each Sample ID.The suffix is always .fastq.gz.The underscores are already there from the source files so need not be changed,and all files have same number of underscores,spaces,and 'Sample' in my case.

Comment: With all those convenient constraints simplifying life, the solution from John1024 looks as though it should work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for fname in *_R1.fastq.gz
do
    base=${fname%_R1*}
    bwa-0.7.5a/bwa mem -t 4 human_g1k_v37.fasta "${base}_R1.fastq.gz"  "${base}_R2.fastq.gz" >"$destdir/${base}_R1_R2.sam"
done
```

In the comments, you ask about running several, but not too many, jobs in parallel.  Below is my first stab at that:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Limit background jobs to no more that $maxproc at once.
maxproc=3

for fname in *  # _R1.fastq.gz
do
    while [ $(jobs | wc -l) -ge "$maxproc" ]
    do
        sleep 1
    done
    base=${fname%_R1*}
    echo starting new job with ongoing=$(jobs | wc -l)
    bwa-0.7.5a/bwa mem -t 4 human_g1k_v37.fasta "${base}_R1.fastq.gz" "${base}_R2.fastq.gz" >"$destdir/${base}_R1_R2.sam" &
done
```

The optimal value of `maxproc` will depend on how many processors your PC has.  You may need to experiment to find what works best.

Note that the above script uses `jobs` which is a bash builtin function.  Thus, it has to be run under bash, not dash which is the default for scripts under Debian-like distributions.

Comment: The answer is great.Is there any way to parallelize this process?I have 50 Sample files (from 50 R1 and 50 R2) to be created,each is huge so takes lot of time.

Comment: The answer is, yes, you can parallelize it.  The "how" depends on what hardware you have available (GPU, multiprocessor, multicomputer, ...) and how `bwa` uses resources.

Comment: I have access to Linux Cluster(Sun grid Engine).Although I was thinking of using "&" inside the for loop, so that the commands run in parallel for each sample?

Comment: If `bwa` uses one processor at a time, then putting `&` in the loop will work up until you have more processes than processors.  Grid sounds good but others will know more about it how to use it than I.

Comment: I am trying to parallelize this using & below,but I believe its not working due to the resources starvation.                                for fname in *_R1.fastq.gz
    do
      base=${fname%_R1*}
    bwa-0.7.5a/bwa mem -t 4 human_g1k_v37.fasta "${base}_R1.fastq.gz"       "${base}_R2.fastq.gz" > "$destdir/${base}_R1_R2.sam" &
   done
   wait

Comment: John,I am working on titan cluster which is  consisting of 464 HP blade systems, two head nodes and a virtualized pool of login (submit) nodes.Each node has eight cores (two quad-core processors), and either 16GB (430 nodes) or 32GB (34 nodes) of memory. This provices 3712 compute cores and 8 TB of total RAM (memory).Using for loop would put each job on the same processor,I think.So ,running an array job so that each job is running parallel on a different processor would be the solution.

Comment: @rohan I have a single multi-core processor and the Linux nicely distributes jobs among the cores.  I cannot help with the Cluster because I know nothing about it: I suggest a new question and see if an expert appears.