# Running parallel Jobs

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, sungridengine, qsub

I am working on titan cluster which is consisting of 464 HP blade systems, two head nodes and a virtualized pool of login (submit) nodes.Each node has eight cores (two quad-core processors), and either 16GB (430 nodes) or 32GB (34 nodes) of memory. This provices 3712 compute cores and 8 TB of total RAM (memory)

The task is to use 2 parts namely R1,R2 for each Sample file.So each Sample file has R1,R2 types present in pairs which are to be used together to create a .sam file ,the reference is human_g1k_v37.fasta,and the software is BWA.I am using for loop for this,however I am not able to parallelize it on the cluster,as it would take very long for each sample to be run one at a time.below script is for running iteratively each pair one at a time(Works)

```
sourcedir=/sourcepath/
destdir=/destinationpath/


for fname in *_R1.fastq.gz
do
base=${fname%_R1*}
bwa-0.7.5a/bwa mem -t 8 human_g1k_v37.fasta "${base}_R1.fastq.gz" "${base}_R2.fastq.gz" >   "$destdir/${base}_R1_R2.sam" 

done
```

Since Using for loop would put each job on the same processor.I tried using "&" but its the same thing I believe and it does not seem to work in this case.I need all these processes to run on different processor parallel (might be an array job??)
Below script does not work (for parallel processing)

```
sourcedir=/sourcepath/
destdir=/destinationpath/


for fname in *_R1.fastq.gz
do
base=${fname%_R1*}
bwa-0.7.5a/bwa mem -t 8 human_g1k_v37.fasta "${base}_R1.fastq.gz" "${base}_R2.fastq.gz" >   "$destdir/${base}_R1_R2.sam" &

done
wait
```

For more details,please see this earlier post of mine.[Looping files in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20893836/looping-files-in-bash/20893952?noredirect=1#comment31522415_20893952)

Thanks

Comment: see if your `man xargs` documentation indicates that it can support `-n` option (I think. n=number of processes). And search here for `[bash] xargs` to see how to use it. Good luck.

Comment: Have you seen this? [Running an array job on Titan cluster](http://wiki.c2b2.columbia.edu/systems/index.php/Documentation/Titan_cluster#Running_an_array_job)

Comment: Yes,I looked at it.My files are 51772BL1_R1.fastq.gz,51772BL1_R2.fastq.gz to be used to generate one sample.Other pair is 51805BL1_R1.fastq.gz,51805BL1_R2.fastq.gz to generate other.Similarly,there are 50 Samples to be created.Since,the array job requires an SGE_TASK_ID,I don't find any pattern in these files that could be used.Do I have to assign some kind of unique patterns to them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just submitting your job to your grid engine, it will handle the parallelization itself :

```
#! /bin/sh
### Your script task.sh ###
#$ -S /bin/sh

bwa-0.7.5a/bwa mem -t 8 human_g1k_v37.fasta "${1}_R1.fastq.gz" "${1}_R2.fastq.gz" > "$destdir/${1}_R1_R2.sam"
```

and then in your loop :

```
for fname in *_R1.fastq.gz
do
    base=${fname%_R1*}
    qsub task.sh ${base}
done
```